# Does the delegate system in the US make it possible to in any way shape or form financially benefit delegates for their vote?

Tags: united-states, politics

Donald Trump said (Source: [USA Today](http://www.usatoday.com/videos/news/politics/elections/2016/2016/04/17/83160410/)) that the delegate system is set up in such a way that you can send the delegate on a nice luxurious vacation which may incline them to vote for you.

Is this possible?

Do we have any evidence or record of a delegate gaining personal luxury benefits funded by a political origin in any way shape or form?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, and it's happened in the past. During the 1976 election, incumbent President Ford was in a primary battle with Ronald Reagan. In order to sway the unbound Mississippi delegation, President Ford rides on Air Force One and state dinners.<sup>[1](http://www.npr.org/2016/04/11/473855290/can-a-candidate-pay-delegates-plus-3-likely-gop-convention-scenarios), [2](http://www.npr.org/podcasts/510310/npr-politics-podcast), [3](http://www.nytimes.com/politics/first-draft/2015/12/11/for-republicans-contested-1976-convention-looms-over-2016-race/), [4](http://www.npr.org/2016/03/13/470271684/1976-the-last-time-republicans-duked-it-out-to-the-last-heated-minute)</sup>

[Uncommitted GOP Delegates Are About To Become The New Political ‘It Girls’](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/uncommitted-gop-delegates_us_56ec294ce4b09bf44a9d16fa):

> when the queen of England arrived at the White House for a sumptuous state dinner, the gentleman the president chose to seat her next to was Clarke Reed, chairman of the largest uncommitted delegation — Mississippi’s, with thirty convention votes.
>
> uncommitted South Carolina delegate Sherry Shealy Martschink [said] she had been invited to the White House for a dinner with the King of Spain.

Here are more examples:

- [Donald Trump will pay travel and lodging for Nevada delegates](http://www.washingtonexaminer.com/trump-to-nev.-delegates-ill-pay-your-travel-hotel-costs/article/2588755)
- [A candidate’s campaign committee can also pay for delegate expenses. Some legal experts believe a campaign could even cover an all-expenses-paid weekend prior to the convention to meet with senior staff at, say, a Trump-owned luxury golf resort in Florida.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/how-far-can-you-go-to-win-support-from-a-republican-delegate/2016/04/10/b5108ef8-ff17-11e5-9203-7b8670959b88_story.html)
- [nothing prevented President Gerald R. Ford from using flights aboard Air Force One to charm delegates in 1976.](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/02/us/politics/republican-convention-delegates.html?_r=0)
- [Plane tickets are another permissible delegate perk. In 2012, Ron Paul’s presidential campaign raised funds to pay for some delegates’ travel expenses to the Republican convention that year in an attempt to challenge presumptive GOP nominee Mitt Romney.](http://www.msnbc.com/msnbc/can-the-republican-nomination-be-bought)

Comment: But however much those things may stroke a feeble ego, they do not seem to be financial benefits,  The benefit of a free meal would likely be much less than the cost of travel to Washington, buying fancy clothing, &c.

Comment: If you want the "financial" answer, you should put it in the text of the question, not only in the title.